# Factorial code in C

Tags: c

It took me a while to figure out how to write this code, but I'm glad to say that I did eventually figure it out.

Can someone tell me what they think about it?  Is it well written? What could have been done better?

Note that I am going through exercises in a book; I know there's a `math.h` that problem solves this, but I don't want to use that since I am not currently in that chapter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("\n Table of Factorials\n\n");
printf(" n ------------- Factorial\n");

int n, factorial, counter; 

factorial = 1;
n = 1;
counter = 1;

for ( ; counter <= 10; ++counter)
{
    for ( ; n <= counter; ++n)
    {   
    factorial = factorial * n;
    }

    printf("%2i --------------%7i\n", counter, factorial);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd move the factorial computation into its own function.

Comment: I hope you understands what happens if you try to get the factorial of 14 or maybe even 40? And why the simple fix isn't the right fix.

Comment: I'm glad to see a non-recursive implementation of factorial.

Comment: Answers below have remarked on the indentation problems, but that seems to have been an artifact of copying-and-pasting the code into the text editor on this site. Markdown syntax requires four leading _spaces_ to form a code block; the Markdown written in the question contained leading tabs instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, your indentation is a bit off. You should be indenting within a function body, so instead of:

```
int main(void)
{
printf(...);
// Other code
}
```

it should be:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf(...);
    // Other code
}
```

Similarly with:

```
for ( ; n <= counter; ++n)
{   
factorial = factorial * n;
}
```

This is something to really watch out for; it makes for a jarring experience when reading the code.

The constant `10` here:

```
for ( ; counter <= 10; ++counter)
```

should be given a name:

```
#define MAX_COUNTER 10

for( ; counter <= MAX_COUNTER; ++counter)
```

The line:

```
factorial = factorial * n;
```

can be simplified into:

```
factorial *= n;
```

Having two loops here is more complex than it needs to be. It can be simplified to just using 1 loop. You could also pull the initialization of counter into this loop:

```
int counter;

for (counter = 1 ; counter <= MAX_COUNTER; ++counter)
{
    factorial *= counter;
    printf("%2i --------------%7i\n", counter, factorial);
}
```

If you're using C99, which allows variable declarations anywhere within a function (not just at the top), this can be simplified even more:

```
int factorial = 1;
for(int counter = 1; counter <= MAX_COUNTER; ++counter) {
    factorial *= counter;
    printf("%2i --------------%7i\n", counter, factorial);
}
```

Comment: Good, I was also wondering what the variable n was for. Maybe a personal idea but I think it's clearer to declare each variable on a single line.

Comment: @dyesdyes I agree, unless the variables belong to each other. For example: float x,y,z; or int screenWidth,screenHeight; That sort of thing.

Comment: Is it me or does the last simplification make no difference to the complexity or number of lines of code?

Comment: @Charleh It limits variable scope to the smallest possible scope. In such a small function it makes almost no difference, but is a good habit to get into (assuming you're using a C99 compatible compiler, and aren't stuck with MSVC).

Comment: Better yet would be `const int MAX_COUNTER=10;`. Doesn't change anything here, but generally it's better to make constants via `const` instead of `#define`.

Comment: @Ruslan I agree, however, while the book has likely introduced `#DEFINE` by this point; I'm less sure about `const`.

Comment: You don't even need a body in the `for` loop. Try: `for(int c = 1 ; c <= MAX_COUNTER ; printf("%2i --- %7i\n", c, (factorial *= c++)));`. This is perhaps somewhat nasty, the result is implementation-dependent (which gets evaluated first, pushing `c` onto the stack to call printf, or the `c++` in the assignment to `factorial`? :-), and you may get arrested for "abuse of a `for` loop" but hey - you saved having to code up a block to follow the `for` statement, and it runs on **my** machine - what could go wrong? :-). And BTW - indentation is a religious issue - not for SO. :-) Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: To be precise, this is not implementation-defined; it is undefined behaviour, and so any result is valid.

Comment: @Yuushi Ah I see what you mean, just compressing variable scope - I'm used to Resharper doing this for me I think I'm getting lazy :)

Answer (score 13):

Looks pretty good!  Just a few minor things:

- Your variables should be on separate lines, which is useful for maintainability and possible commenting.  They can also be initialized instead of declared and then assigned.

  ```
  int n = 1;
  int factorial = 1;
  int counter = 1;
  ```
- Instead of this:

  ```
  factorial = factorial * n;
  ```

  you can just have this:

  ```
  factorial *= n;
  ```

  This works for any of the mathematical operators.
- Instead of hard-coding the `10`, you can have the user provide the number of values to display.

  ```
  puts("Enter the number of values to display: ");
  int numValues;
  scanf("%d", &numValues);

  for (int counter = 1; counter <= numValues; counter++)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Start by fixing your indentation.  Lines of code inside each pair of braces should be indented by another level.  I won't start any discussions about exactly how many spaces, but it's imperative that you do it consistently.

Your for-loop is missing the initializer field.  That is legal in C, but you should consider it a red flag.  In the case of your outer for-loop, you should just initialize `counter` there.  Then you have a proper for-loop!  In C99 (which is what nearly everyone uses these days), you can even move the `int` declaration into the for-loop initializer.

Next, tighten up your variable declarations.  You can declare and define on the same line for better readability.

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("\n Table of Factorials\n\n");
    printf(" n ------------- Factorial\n");

    int factorial = 1;
    int n = 1;

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; ++counter)
    {
        for ( ; n <= counter; ++n)
        {
            factorial = factorial * n;
        }

        printf("%2i --------------%7i\n", counter, factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm still not happy with that, though.  Notice…

- Your table is supposed to display *n* and *n*!, but your `printf()` mentions `counter`.
- Your inner for-loop is still missing an initializer.

It turns out that your `n` and `counter` variables are redundant.  This simpler program produces the same output:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("\n Table of Factorials\n\n");
    printf(" n ------------- Factorial\n");

    int factorial = 1;
    for (int n = 1; n <= 10; ++n)
    {
        factorial *= n;
        printf("%2i --------------%7i\n", n, factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation scheme "discussions" often devolve into religious/flame wars. Most dev tools include a code formatter - set it up to your preference, use it (dare I say?) religiously, and co-exist. :-) Share and enjoy.